# Insert inside a div within a table row

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, html-table

I have a table having div in alternate rows. Want to add table inside those divs.

Please check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHK4/33/) and update it for me.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>foo 2 </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("table tr input").on('click', function(e){
    alert($(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
    alert($(this).closest("tr").index()+1);
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").index()+1;
    $('table tr:row').find('div').append("<table><tr><td>hi</td></tr></table>");
});
```

Comment: So what is your problem,code is working ,correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to Insert row at the position and try to check if div exists or not! 
Though Your question is not quite clear but still give this a try.

```
$("table tr input").on('click', function(e){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").index() + 1; // Get index 
    if($('table tr').eq(row).find('div').length > 0); // Check if alternate row contains div
        $('table tr').eq(row).find('div').append("<table><tr><td>hi</td></tr></table>"); // Append table to div
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHK4/32/)

---

**Updated**

As we're checking if div exists or not, no need to take index values of rows, you can directly traverse through the `DOM` to your expected `div` element.

```
$("table tr input").on('click', function(e){
    if($(this).closest("tr").next().find('div').length > 0)
      $(this).closest("tr").next().find('div').append("<table><tr><td>hi</td></tr></table>");
});
```

*Docs:*

[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[<kbd>**Updated Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHK4/38/)

Hope you need this!

Comment: [Fiddle](jsfiddle.net/zwHK4/36/) not working for multiple rows

Comment: yeah it helped me.. but if on click loads different table with text boxes and then returning these values on to this desired div table... thats why i was looking for index

Answer (score 0):

If there are as many divs as inputs you can use the same index:

```
$("table tr input").on('click', function(e){
    var row = $("table tr input").index(this);
    $("table div").eq(row).append("<table><tr><td>hi</td></tr></table>");
});
```